# How to draw a diamond shape in java?

Tags: java, arraylist, geometry, shapes, graphics2d

So i have to draw a diamond shape. Not a Static diamond but a  diamond that i will myself drag and draw. I've used General Path to do it but it is drawing a diamond that is not straight; the diamond is bend to the left and it's not being drawn to where my mouse is pointed.

[image]

Here is my code to create the diamond shape. Can someone please help me solve this?

```html
 private GeneralPath drawDiamond(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){
            
            int x = Math.min(x1, x2);
            int y = Math.min(y1, y2);

            // Gets the difference between the coordinates and

            int width = Math.abs(x1 - x2);
            int height = Math.abs(y1 - y2);
            
            Rectangle2D.Double diamond = new Rectangle2D.Double(x1,y1,width,height);
            
            GeneralPath connectedDiamond = new GeneralPath(GeneralPath.WIND_EVEN_ODD);
            
            connectedDiamond.append(diamond, true);
            
            AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
            at.rotate(Math.toRadians(20));
            connectedDiamond.transform(at);
            
            return connectedDiamond;
        }
```

Here is my paint method:

```html
public void paint(Graphics g) {           

            graphSettings = (Graphics2D) g;           

            graphSettings.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

            graphSettings.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4));
           
            Iterator<Color> strokeCounter = shapeStroke.iterator();
            for (NamedShape s : shapes) {

                graphSettings.draw(s.getShape());

            }

            if (drawStart != null && drawEnd != null) {
                
                graphSettings.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(
                        AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.40f));

                graphSettings.setPaint(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

                Shape aShape = null;
                    
                if(currentAction == 7){
                    
                    aShape = drawDiamond(drawStart.x, drawStart.y, drawEnd.x, drawEnd.y);
                }

                graphSettings.draw(aShape);
            }
        }
```

Can someone please help me to do this?

Comment: Shouldn't you rotate it 90 degrees?

Comment: @MadProgrammer When i rotate it to 90 degrees, it's not being drawn at all.

Comment: @PieterDeBie When i put to to 45 degrees, the shape is drawn but it's not drawn at my mouse position. How can i solve that>

Comment: Is your pivot point in the center of your rectangle?

Comment: This might explain what I mean: http://i.stack.imgur.com/KZ6Sc.png

Comment: A diamond is not a rectangle except if that rectangle is a square... sides of a diamond must have the same length, if you use a rectangle it will always look "bended"

Comment: Thank you guys! :) i've used line2D to do it.

Comment: @PieterDeBie Yes, 45, brain has left the building

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about instead of rotating a rectangle, you draw lines between 4 points inside a rectangle:

the points:

[image]

excuse my poor mspaint skills.

but i hope u get what i mean. u take the top center, middle right, bottom center and middle left points and draw lines between those (using generalPath, i think)

Comment: Thank you so much :) i've used line2D to do it.

Comment: if im not mistaken you can use GeneralPath's moveTo and lineTo functions to draw lines, you may want to look into that

Comment: Thank you. This might be useful too.

Answer (score 4):

The 2D Shape API is actually really powerful, one of my favourite classes is the `Path2D`, it allows you to simply "draw" a virtual shape, for example

```
public class Diamond extends Path2D.Double {

    public Diamond(double width, double height) {
        moveTo(0, height / 2);
        lineTo(width / 2, 0);
        lineTo(width, height / 2);
        lineTo(width / 2, height);
        closePath();
    }

}
```

Now, you need to make use of an `AffineTransformation` or translate the `Graphics` context to position it, but that's not that hard

[image: Diamonds are forever]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class JavaApplication251 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JavaApplication251();
    }

    public JavaApplication251() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private Diamond diamond;

        public TestPane() {
            diamond = new Diamond(100, 100);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            int x = (getWidth() - diamond.getBounds().width) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight()- diamond.getBounds().height) / 2;
            AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x, y);
            Shape shape = at.createTransformedShape(diamond);
            g2d.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            g2d.fill(shape);
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.draw(shape);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

    public class Diamond extends Path2D.Double {

        public Diamond(double width, double height) {
            moveTo(0, height / 2);
            lineTo(width / 2, 0);
            lineTo(width, height / 2);
            lineTo(width / 2, height);
            closePath();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: can i use path2D to draw a triangle too? But i would like to drag and draw the triangle. Can i use path2D to do this?

Comment: @Lana You had better believe it...for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27393856/inclined-plane-java-triangle-with-angle/27394414#27394414), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12810057/keeping-draw-graphics-removing-super-paintcomponent/12810527#12810527) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676364/flipping-shape-not-image/13676513#13676513)

Answer (score 3):

It would be simpler to create diamond as polygon with vertices

```
(x + Width/2, y)
(x + Width, y + Height/2)
(x + Width/2, y + Height)
(x, y + Height/2)
```